# xamarin forms PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden set to true not working when navigating to other page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have set my content page like below on all my xaml based on the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-home-indicator

<ContentPage ...
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
ios:Page.PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden="true">
...

also tried it in code behind

On().SetPrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden(true);

It's working on first load of the page, but it's not when you navigate to next page.

Comment: I am not exactly clear on the context here. Do you set the same property on the next page as well but despite that the home indicator still shows up?

Comment: Yes I have set the same property on the next page as well but it doesn't work if you navigate to it. Only on the page loaded first. I have also tried to change the startup page to see if it's working, same behavior, it works on first loaded page and it doesn't on the next page when you navigate.

Answer (score 0):

does it only work on the page you put

```
ios:Page.PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden="true"
```

If yes, you have to put it in the header of the next page too. In Fact you have to put it on all the pages you want the home indicator hidden. The next page does not know preferences from previous page - as long as you dont use templates.

Comment: Yes I have set the same property on the next page as well but it doesn't work if you navigate to it. Only on the page loaded first. I have also tried to change the startup page to see if it's working, same behavior, it works on startup page and it doesn't on the next page when you navigate.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` property,it doesn't mean that HomeIndicator is completely hidden,it just keeps it from showing all the time.Each time the screen is touched, the Home Indicator pops up again and disappears after about two or three seconds of touching.

Comment: Yes, but in my case it is not being hidden on the next page even without touching the screen. Also when u go back to the previous page it is not being hidden at all as well.

Comment: What's your Xamarin.forms version ?It works on my side with the latest version.

Comment: Just updated xamarin forms to version 4.8.0.1560 today, still not working when you navigate to next page. Have you tried navigating to another page? I'm using Prism navigation btw.

Comment: Yes,i navigate to another page ,and 2~3 seconds later,if i don't touch it,the HomeIndicator will disappear.

Comment: I'm using Prism navigation. Are you doing it in simulator or real iPhone X device?

Comment: I test it in a simulator and i don't use Prism.

Comment: I confirmed that it's working when not using Prism Navigation.

Comment: There seems to be a difference in Prism Navigation.